# Illustrator CC - Moving Objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've only had Illustrator CC for about 2 weeks so I'm still getting used to some of the differences from CS6. When I move an object, like text, there is a preview of where the text will be placed. However, when I move an embedded image (transparent PNG), the only preview I can see is the bounding box (transform controls) which, as you know, usually isn't the exact size of the content.

Is there any way to see the preview when moving an embedded image? Even making the bounding box the same size as the content would work. It makes it really hard to make the image the same size as something else in the document and it is especially difficult to perfectly place it on top of something. I looked through the prefs but came up short. The only thing preview related is "Use preview bounds" and that didn't change anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No. this is just how Illustrator works with raster images. AI has always merely shown the original bounding rectangle for the image when moving it.